# Trying to recreate "pipeline script from SCM" section of a Jenkins job in DSL code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using Jenkins version 1.658 and Job DSL plugin in version 1.43, I'm working on converting an existing Pipeline job into a DSL-generated job.
The original job has a "pipeline script from SCM" section, and I can't seem to find the code to create it in DSL.
I know in newer versions of the DSL plugin I have the cpsScm configuration that works for this section, but it's not suitable for the version I'm using.
So I've tried to create this with the configure section in code, when I'm stating the plugin versions that are used in the job.

Here's one of my tries:

```
configure {
    def workflow = it / 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition' (plugin: 'workflow-cps@2.23') {
    workflow << it / 'scm' / 'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM' (plugin: 'git@3.0.3') {
            configVersion 2
        }
    }
```

This is how this part looks like in the config.xml of the Jenkins job I'm working on:

```
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@2.9">
.
.
.
<definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@2.23">
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@3.0.3">
<configVersion>2</configVersion>
<userRemoteConfigs>
<hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
<url>https://github.com/XXXXX.git</url>
<credentialsId>XXXXX</credentialsId>
</hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
</userRemoteConfigs>
<branches>
<hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
<name>master</name>
</hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
</branches>
<doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
<submoduleCfg class="list"/>
<extensions/>
</scm>
<scriptPath>buildScripts/workflow_deploy.groovy</scriptPath>
</definition>
<triggers/>
</flow-definition>
```

When I'm trying to create the job using this code, it's adding a "Pipeline script" box instead of "pipeline script from SCM".
I know this is a very specific case and the versions are old, but I'm just trying to figure out how this nested class inside of class can be translated into DSL code.

thanks!